# Logic puzzle to prove which relative is male or female?

Tags: puzzle

C, D, E, F, G, H, and I are the father, mother, aunt, brother, sister, wife and daughter of J, but you do not know which is which. But you know that:

- E and F are the same gender.
- C and D are of different genders.
- H was born before C
- F is not the mother of J.

Referring to the above information, which one of the following must be true?

- C is female.
- D is female.
- E is female.
- F is male.
- H is male.

Comment: I've spent an hour staring at this puzzle so far - I'm utterly stuck. Even a clue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there are only two males among C, D, E, F, G, H, and I.
Now E and F are the same gender. Consider the case that they are male. This would imply rest are female and this would contradict that C and D are of different genders. **So E and F should be female**

'E is female' must be true

Answer (score 2):

See there are two males among the $7$ persons.

Consider that $E,F$ are males then except $E,F$ all must be females so $C,D$ cannot be of different genders which contradicts the hypothesis so $E,F$ must be females.Thus third option that $E$ is female is necessarily true.

You can easily check that all other options are not necessarily true.